# Ruby array include? method weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm using the cancan gem, and in ability.rb, I wanted to check if a user with a certain role can update another object if and only if the user 'is part of' the other object (that is, there is an association between the models, and the user is found in the object's `users` method).

I wanted to use the `include?` method to see if `@current_user` is found in the resulting `User` array.

It always returns `false` when testing the code through ability.rb. If I run the same code in the rails console, it works fine.

I found out that `include?` does not work if the `Array` objects are not of the same class as the passed object, but I printed their class through `class.name`, and they are the same.

I ended up using `detect` and comparing id's, but I wanted to know if anyone has had this kind of issue before, and if you could shed some light on this.

Something similar happened with `delete_if`, where after deleting 20 out of a 100, count was still returning 100, but an each loop printed only the ones that were supposed to be there (20). This happened when executing within the RoR environment, but the rails console with the same code behaved as expected (`array.count # => 20`).

EDIT 20131007

A bit of code regarding the `include?` issue. 
This bit returns false all the time, even though the user IS in the resulting array from `course.institution.users`.

```
    can [:read, :update], Course do |course|
      val = course.institution.users.include? user
    end
```

If I take that same line, and try it for a given course and user in the rails console, like so:

```
    Course.find(course_id).institution.users.include? User.find(user_id)
```

It works as it's supposed to, returning `true` then the user is found in the array and `false` if not.

So even, *even* if the `==` operator was weird in some way for this particular model, I'm dealing with the same arrays in both cases, so it should either bust or work well in *both* cases, not only within the cancan `ability.rb`... right?

Comment: Could you add a code snippet or a repro case?

Comment: Hard to say without code example but would bet you are comparing apples with oranges. Just examine equality operator `==` of your objects to ensure expected behavior of `Array#include?` and other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Cancan has a built-in mechanism to query associations. Without knowing your exact setup, this should be close to how you could set this up in your `Ability` class:

```
can :view, MyObject, users: { id: user.id }
```